# remove all digits from string except dates

Tags: php

I need to block all digits from a string except dates

I tried some regexp but i dont know how to exclude

**Example string**

> 02/08/2017 *[or 02-08-2017 or 02.08.2017]* sent email requesting call back to schedule a visit. Jane Doe is 17 years old and her phone number is 8373763545
>   Jane Doe wrote 3rd April 2019 12:19 :   i live in street 123 in New York

i tried something with `/(\d{4}[\.\/\-][01]\d[\.\/\-][0-3]\d)/`

but i dont know how to exclude the dates and block the other digits

**I need**

> 02/08/2017 *[or 02-08-2017 or 02.08.2017]* sent email requesting call back to schedule a visit. Jane Doe is ** years old and her phone number is ********
>   Jane Doe wrote 3rd April 2019 12:19 :   i live in street *** in New York

Comment: If this is a user generated content then this approach is going to be fraught with difficulties - what if somone set's their phone number as `83-73-6354 ... 5.` ? 

And the value `3rd April 2019 12:19`; is also ripe for abuse. You need a better way of approaching this issue.

Comment: I would start by matching what you want to include. Which would mean all non-numeric characters `[^\d]` and date formats. (You will need to make your own list of accepted formats). After that you can invert your match and replace the characters

Comment: If you simply want to remove strings of numbers longer than x value (say, 4) then there are plenty of regex to do this such as `\d{5,}` or `[\d\/\\h-]{5,}`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify the code according to your needs, but I hope the following would be a good start:

```
// Your text
$text = '02/08/2017 [or 02-08-2017 or 02.08.2017] sent email requesting call back to schedule a visit. Jane Doe is 17 years old and her phone number is 8373763545 Jane Doe wrote 3rd April 2019 12:19 : i live in street 123 in New York';

// To avoid inaccuracies specify a list of possible date formats
// For more details see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
$date_formats = [
    'd/m/Y',
    'd.m.Y',
    'd-m-Y',
    'jS F Y H:i'
];

// Define expressions that must match the string containing a date
$date_long_expr = '\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th) [a-z]{3,9} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}';

// In order do not to match a date inside some number, capture a wide range of numeric values
$date_short_expr = '[\d./-]+';

// When defining the regex, make sure to use expressions in descending order of their length
// This is necessary to prevent the replacement of characters that can be used by longer ones
$rgxp = "#$date_long_expr|$date_short_expr#i";

// Start the search and replace process
$text = preg_replace_callback($rgxp, function($m) use($date_formats) {
    foreach ($date_formats as $format) {
        // Each date or numeric value found will be converted to DateTime instance
        $dt = date_create_from_format($format, $m[0]);

        // Consider it a valid date only if the found value is equal to value returned by DateTime instance
        if ($dt && $dt->format($format) == $m[0]) {
            return $m[0];
        }
    }

    // Hide digits if the value does not match any date format
    return preg_replace('#\d#', '*', $m[0]);
}, $text);

echo $text; //-> "02/08/2017 [or 02-08-2017 or 02.08.2017] sent email requesting call back to schedule a visit. Jane Doe is ** years old and her phone number is ********** Jane Doe wrote 3rd April 2019 12:19 : i live in street *** in New York"
```

Comment: seems very cool but when i do this string it does not work. Jan Doe wrote 4th April 2019 09:48 :     The string could be much longer or shorter and can be placed in a longer text

Comment: @EdwinSwart This is because `$date_long_expr` matched only ordinal numbers  1st, 2nd, and 3rd. I updated my answer and now it should match `th`.